# Why is Banner the way he is in the Shang-Chi post credits scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, the-incredible-hulk, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Hulk/Banner (smart hulk?) is the default form for Bruce Banner. However, in the credits scene of *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, Bruce is shown as a standard human (or as standard human as Banner gets). Why is he no longer Smart Hulk by the time of *Shang-Chi*?

Comment: Think it was explained in the first episode of She-Hulk, but kinda trying to forget that series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Banner in Shang-Chi (and at the start of She-Hulk) is wearing a special device that makes him stay in his human form.

> “When you first come into Bruce and Jen in the car in the first
> episode, you kind of hear the tailend of the conversation. And really
> that conversation is just him talking about how he discovered that his
> arm could heal better when he was in human form, so he created that
> little device that you see him wearing to keep him in human form just
> so that he can heal his arm and then go back to being Smart Hulk. And
> that's why when the device breaks in the car accident, he turns back
> into Smart Hulk. And because we were doing all of this, that's
> actually why we kind of planted Bruce in Banner form in Shang-Chi.”
>
> <sub><sup>[She-Hulk Producer Clarifies Shang-Chi Post-Credits Confusion](https://thedirect.com/article/she-hulk-shang-chi-post-credits-confusion)</sup></sub>